# Intellij Can't Find My Tests Using JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

Intellij complains that it cannot find any tests. "No tests were found", it says.

My `src/test/java` folder is green, marked for tests.  We use gradle, and I have `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` configured in the `dependencies`. everything resolves and compiles.

```
// my-test-file.java
package com.my-company.some-service;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotEquals;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.util.UUID;

class MyClass extends TestCase {
    ...

    @Before
    void setUpContributor() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    void testAnnounce() {
        ...
}
```

Comment: your test class should be public. and if you want use junit 3 framework, your test method also should be public.

Comment: Side notes: Since you are using junit 4 there is no need extend TestCase. Btw. you should avoid to use any Class from `junit.**` but instead use `org.junit.**`
How are you running the tests? right click on the java folder and `run tests?`

Comment: doh! `public` was the magic touch.  thanks @walsh!  and i patched up the imports, thanks @meistermeier